# Oracle query DATE field by hour

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Trying to convert an informix query to Oracle 11g.

This gives me the integer hour from a datetime stamp.

```
create_dtim::datetime hour to hour::char(2)::int
```

The hours are 24hrs format like  0,1,2,3,4....

I'm trying to accomplish the same in Oracle but no luck. I have so far

```
 TRUNC(start_dtim, 'HH24')
```

but this is giving me a format like this

```
3/9/2015 7:00:00 AM
```

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use TO_CHAR to convert the date fields

```
select TO_CHAR (start_dtim, 'HH24')
from yourtable
/
```

Comment: Great. thanks! I added to_number to clean up a bit TO_NUMBER(to_CHAR(start_dtim, 'HH24'))... thank you!